# Sitecore: InvalidOperationException: Post condition failed

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore7

I'm relatively new to Sitecore.

In my Pre-Prod server I'm getting below error whenever I click on Content Editor. Page Editor seems to work fine. Please help.

> InvalidOperationException: Post condition failed

Log Details are below:

> Exception: System.InvalidOperationException Message: Post condition
>   failed Source: Sitecore.Kernel at
>   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ResultNotNull[T](T result, String message)
>   at
>   Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Data.DataViewFactory.GetDataViewByName(String
>   name) at
>   Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Data.DataViewFactory.GetDataView(String
>   name, String parameters) at
>   Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.DataContext.GetItem(String id) at
>   Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.DataContext.GetState(Item& root, Item&
>   folder, Item[]& selected

Comment: You should be able to get the stack trace from the log file, which by default is found in \data\logs. If you can get that, then append to your question and it will help us to diagnose the problem.

Comment: You're going to need to add more detail if you want an answer. What's the stack trace for the error? What configuration changes have been made to from the working server to the not working one? What version of Sitecore? What extra modules have been installed?

Comment: And one thing you need to remember, it's **Sitecore**, not SiteCore!

Comment: Pls find the log details below:

Comment: Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Post condition failed
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ResultNotNull[T](T result, String message)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Data.DataViewFactory.GetDataViewByName(String name)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Data.DataViewFactory.GetDataView(String name, String parameters)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.DataContext.GetItem(String id)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.DataContext.GetState(Item& root, Item& folder, Item[]& selected

Comment: What do you mean by "click on Content Editor"? Do you try to open Content Editor? Do you try to select particular/any item in Content Editor?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like something is not right with the config files in the site.

It's very hard to tell exactly what is the issue with that error message. And finding the issue will more than likely be a process of elimination.

I would suggest the the best course of action is to compare the configuration of the site with a known working version or a basic Sitecore install with no customisations. You can use the ShowConfig tool in Sitecore to show you all the configuration settings after the includes (as the config does not just consist of Web.config). More info on this here: -https://sitecorejohn.wordpress.com/2010/03/11/tool-to-examine-sitecore-web-config-after-accounting-for-include-files/

It's worth checking the App_config/include  directory in Sitecore to see if you have any modules in place (E.g. Sitecore.MediaFramework.config) that are not in place where your site is working. You can disable these config settings by renaming the file to be .example.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question but in case it helps someone.

Very likely you are trying to access Sitecore Content Editor from your CD node.

Access Sitecore from CM only.